# How to get ID of input field from form using jQuery element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form with each input field unique id and I have attached jquery on 'input' to form. I want to get id of field on which user change some value using jquery function. I am missing some puzzle in following code in alert(".... statement

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").on('input', function () {

        alert($(this).find().closest().attr('id'));

    });

});
```

### html form

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Student UWL ID must be a number." data-val-range="Only Number Allowed" data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="Require Your Student UWL ID" id="StudentNumber_UWLID" name="StudentNumber_UWLID" value="" type="number">
```

I have many instances of input field like above

Comment: `closest()` what ? Maybe you just want `event.target.id` ?

Comment: find what and closest what?

Comment: may be you want $(this).attr('id') ???

Comment: As I see, this is not the `complete` HTML

Comment: @Tushar I think OP wants $(this).attr('id')

Comment: $(this).find().closest() $(this).childrens().parents() methods are similar.

Comment: Why would the OP want `this.id` when he already has the ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if you attach the event to each field individually?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").find("input,textarea,select").on('input', function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="CreateStudentProfileForm">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <input type="text" id="input3">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to track the change event for an input use change event

```
   //assuming you input id is CreateStudentProfileForm
   $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").on('change', function () {
    alert(this.id) //should give you the changed input id
    //alert($(this).find().closest().attr('id'));

   });
```

`keyup` is better

```
  $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").keyup(function () {
    alert(this.id)
    //alert($(this).find().closest().attr('id'));

});
```

**updated**

this gets all the input present in you form specified by id `CreateStudentProfileForm` and adds keyup event to track the changes.

```
//assuming CreateStudentProfileForm is form's ID
$("#CreateStudentProfileForm:input").keyup(function () {
    alert(this.id) //should give you the changed inputs id
    //alert($(this).find().closest().attr('id'));

   });
```

Comment: already op has wrong code, don't you feel .find().closest() do what? and you're also doing the same.

Comment: sorry I haven't voted nagative on you anwer but this doesn't work!

Comment: @toxic you want the id of changed input? if so than I have update my answer.check it out

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#CreateStudentProfileForm').on('change keyup','input', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id')
})
```

"id" is the id you want...

Answer (score 1):

do something like this  http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/kqvdgrmk/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#CreateStudentProfileForm input").keyup(function(){

    alert(this.id);    
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```
this.id;
```

Or get:

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a similar HTML

```
<form id="CreateStudentProfileForm">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <input type="text" id="input3">
</form>
```

Then you can do something like

```
$('#CreateStudentProfileForm > input').on('input change', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Note that this event will fire on both `input` and `change`. You may want to fire it only on change OR input, depending on what you need to do.

Comment: This might not be the best way to go about it. First of all, input will trigger every time, even if you paste data into field. "change" will trigger only when the input loses focus. Another issue is that your code will work only for input type elements (he may have select, textarea elements as well); and finally this will work only for elements that are direct ascendants of the form element and will not work if he has a more complext HTML structure withing the form.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should use only one event trigger between input and change, according to what you need, and the question stated he needed the input trigger.
Yes, the selector is pretty strict, that is the best way to go with the given example. You can always change the selector according your needings.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () 
{$("#CreateStudentProfileForm").find("input").on('input', function () {var get_id = $(this).attr('id');});});